# System.NullReferenceException - but Debugger shows value is non-null

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I'm working on a research paper about plugin-architecture and I'm trying to recreate [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4691/Plugin-Architecture-using-C) code. Now I got everything right and my dll file is in the right directory, but when I run my code I get an System.NullReferenceException. This is, off cource, not an uncommon Exception for me to see, but there's something odd about it. Normally when I see this exception I add a couple of breakpoint and see where it's breaking, so that's just what I did and then I found out that, at the point where the Exception is thrown, the object is not null! Can anybody explain this?

This is the code I'd like to run:

```
            string args = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);

            Type oType = null;
            try
            {
                Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile(file);

                if (asm == null) return;
                Type[] types = asm.GetTypes();
                foreach (Type t in types)
                {
                    // CHECK IF CURRENT TYPE IMPLEMENTS INTERFACE IPlugin
                    if (typeof(IPlugin).IsAssignableFrom(t))
                    {
                        IPlugin plugin = (IPlugin)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
                        plugin.Host = this;
                        plugins.Add(plugin);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
```

This is the exception being thrown:
[image: The exception]

The object that is not null:

[image: The object]

One more thing. I think it might have something to do with 'this' not yet being initialized, but I can't figure out how to call this method after my constructor's finished. I tried using various events to call my function, but they didn't make anything better.

[edit]

The Host property:

```
// Register the plugin if host is set
    public IPluginHost Host { 
        get
        {
            return host;
        }
        set 
        { 
            host = value;
            host.Register(this); 
        } 
    }
```

[another edit]
Apparently the code's breaking in the plugins.Add(plugin) line!

```
public bool Register(IPlugin plugin)
    {
        plugins.Add(plugin);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: What line of code is triggering the exception? `plugin.Host = this;`? Are you sure it's not the line immediately preceding (which would trigger a NullReferenceException if `t` is null)? Or after (`plugins` might be null)?

Comment: Sugest ex.ToString() not .Message.

Comment: Nice, finally a question with a NRE in it that I didn't immediately down-vote. +1 for using the debugger! When you find the issue, even if there are no answers, make sure to self-answer and explain the issue and how it was found. Good luck.

Comment: Are you sure `plugins` isn't null?  I sometimes see the debugger highlighting an incorrect line when breaking on an exception, for reasons I do not know.  Another possiblility is that the `Host` setter is throwing the exception, if that's not your code.

Comment: Is plugin.host and this of the same type?

Comment: To that point, step through the code line by line and make doubly-sure you know what line is triggering the NRE.

Comment: Yes, plugin.host and this are of the same type.

Comment: And the Exception is definitely triggered by plugin.Host = this;
@MichaelPetrotta, t is not null, it iterates throught t 2 times before giving the exception.

Comment: To begin with you could add `if ( plugin != null ) {...}` to check if `Activator` sucessfully creates instance on every iteration of the loop

Comment: Not sure if you picked up on phoog's full meaning: any funny business going on in the `Host` setter?

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov, did it, still getting the exception!

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta, I added the Host setter to the question as reference!

Comment: So there *is* something interesting in the setter. What is `Register` doing? Dollars to donuts it's causing the NRE. Try stepping through it.

Comment: Just stepped through it, and it is in fact causing the NRE, however, I still don't know why. I shall update my question.

Comment: So `plugins` seem to be null...

Comment: It was. Got my answer, thanks!

Comment: I would also add, this is kind of a puzzle....everything is named `plugin` or `plugins`...it is very confusing. This naming brought you to this problem. Consider changing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TargetSite is listed as `Boolean Register(Plugin_api.Plugin)`, so that's where the NullReferenceException is thrown. Set a breakpoint in your `plugins.Add` method, it would appear that your internal backing List is null, not the plugin you try to put in it :)

`Edit:` after seeing your update, it appears that plugins is Null from all that I can see. Is plugins a simple `List`? Or a custom class? What does Add do? Set a breakpoint in that Register line and see what it does. In case you initialize Plugins through a static/global object there may also be a Heisenbug (a bug that doesn't appear under the debugger because the debugger changes the state of your app), but that's really just a guess.